# Advantage of bulkloading in a B-Tree

Tags: data-structures, search-trees, efficiency, balanced-search-trees

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Initial_construction

Currently I know of 2 ways for building a B-Tree : bulkloading and just inserting key after key.

In the wiki example the keys are sorted, which I guess is a condition for this bulkloading concept.

What is the advantage of bulkloading if the keys are unsorted ?
 because I have to sort them myself still resulting in O(nlogn) , same as inserting key after key in the B-Tree.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: asymptotic runtime is not the only interesting characteristic of an algorithm.

Comment: @adrianN the wiki article didn't mention why it's really done , my first thought was that this building technique is used to reduce the asymptotic runtime

Comment: Because you sort "flat data", so with bulk loaded data you save (mean) time of the tree traversal and (possibly) some splits that could be avoided knowing data in advance.